# 2d tile based map - How to repeat map on edges?

Tags: c#, algorithm, xna-4.0

I'm making a platformer, with tile based map (like a lot of people). I begin in video games's developing so it's a little hard. I wan't to learn by myself but on this problem I'm stuck .

My maps are made with a list like this :

```
mapList[x][y] = tile
```

With this list, I can loop on all the Tiles and draw them.

What I want to do is to "Loop" (repeat) the map. I mean, when the character reach the right limit (or left), the map repeats. I don't understand how to do this, I search all the forums and all the question, but I found nothing :(

[For instance](http://img69.xooimage.com/files/1/e/a/repeat-3284c77.png)

I don't know if I'm making myself clear but English is not my best language and i'm sorry for this :p.

Thanks in advance for trying to help me or just for reading my issue.

Comment: Use [Modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) according to your boundaries

Comment: I am too tired to write a complete answer ( especially since you are not telling us are you having problems with drawing or with the implementing it in general ), but you can repeat tiles by accessing tiles like this: `mapList[x % MAP_WIDTH][y % MAP_HEIGHT]`

Comment: @JaakkoLipsanen Great ! Thank you both, I'll try work this way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a grid that is WxH cells, the valid ranges for X are 0..W-1

So as a first approach :

```
 int nextX = (X+1) % W;   // wraps around to 0
```

but you'll also need something for prevX (X-1) and maybe for X+d where d can be positive or negative.
You don't want to mess with the modulo of negative numbers, so

```
 int MoveX(int d) { return (X+W+d) % W; }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. But there is a thing that I don't understand. How can I "show" the "next" and "previous" tiles. I draw my actual tiles with this loops http://pastebin.com/R747q4dV. Anyway, thank you for your first answer :) I'll learn.